# Delete all files except in array in NodeMCU Lua

Tags: arrays, file, lua, nodemcu

Delete all files except the files in array
`files = {"init.lua", "client.lua", "config.htm", "server.lua", "update.lua"}`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/), you can get a list of all the files on the filesystem using [`file.list()`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/file/#filelist).

This returns a map `file name => file size`; so the filename is the table key, which you can make use of.

Keep in mind that:

- Table indexing in Lua is acceptably fast
- Key-Value pairs can be removed by setting the value to `nil`

So we can do something like this:

```lua
local whitelist = {"init.lua", "client.lua", "config.htm", "server.lua", "update.lua"}
local files = file.list()

-- Remove files found in the whitelist
for _, filename in ipairs(whitelist) do
   files[filename] = nil
end

-- Delete the remaining files
for filename in pairs(files) do
   file.remove(filename)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we can create 3 array-like tables: one for the protected files (the one you provided), another to list all files in the directory and the last to select the files we will delete.

```
local protected = {"init.lua", "client.lua", "config.htm", "server.lua", "update.lua"}
local found = {}
local delete = {}
```

Next, we will gather the directory contents:

```
for name in io.popen([[dir "" /b]]):lines() do
   table.insert(found, name)
end
```

It is worth noticing that it will get folders too, but it doesn't matter here, since we won't be able to delete these anyway.

Now, with a simple function and a for-loop we will get the values from `found` to `delete` except for the ones in `protected`:

```
local function contains(t, v)
    for index, value in ipairs(t) do
        if value == v then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

for _, value in ipairs(found) do
   if not contains(protected, value) then
      table.insert(delete, value)
   end
end
```

Now we delete the files in `delete`

```
for _, filename in ipairs(delete) do
   print("Deleting "..filename.." (unless it is a folder)")
   os.remove(filename) -- this function is simply unable to delete folders
end
```

And this is it. I must admit, I'm running it on Windows, so I used the `dir` command. Where you want to run it may need it to be changed to `ls` (from `io.popen([[dir "" /b]]):lines()` to `io.popen([[ls "" /b]]):lines()`).